# Jssor slider how to retrieve right<-->left sliding status of the slider

Tags: javascript, slider, jssor

I'm **trying to retrieve left/right status when sliding** but i can't figure out how to get the information. I get **TRUE** when the slider is sliding and **FALSE** when not.

myInstance.$IsSliding(); // Return true/false

With reference from the Jssor documentation under API:
$IsSliding()
//Retrieve right<-->left sliding status of the slider

I expect to get left right status, but when I check in the core file **jssor.slider.js**, the only thing I see with left / right is this:

```
    _SelfSlider.$IsSliding = function () {
        /// <summary>
        ///     instance.$IsSliding();   //Retrieve right<-->left sliding status of the slider.
        /// </summary>
        return _IsSliding;
    };
```

the **_IsSliding** in the core files is only assigned true/false 
as I see it.

How can I get this information from the API?

---

**I ended up doing this:**

```
 slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, function(position, fromPosition)
    {

        if (sliderLock === false) {

            if (position > fromPosition) {
                console.log(Math.ceil(position));
                console.log("next");
                addElementsToScroller(Math.ceil(position));
            } else {
                console.log("prev");
                console.log(Math.floor(position));
                addElementsToScroller(Math.floor(position));
            }
        }

        sliderLock = true;

});
```